# How to sumif values between two times

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have a list of contracts that run for a month, each line is a separate contract that is active during this times. I need to know what is the sum value between 00:00 and 01:00 (which is 8). What formula can I use. I tried sumif but the problem is that I can't figure out how to include the values for lines as 00:00 to 00:00 which means this contract runs for 24 hours and also contract starting at 23:00 preceding day till 05:00.

```
Jan
start  end   value
00:00  05:00   5
05:00  10:00   5
23:00  05:00   2
00:00  00:00   1
```

Thank you,

Comment: What tells you that starting at `23:00` and ending at `05:00` results in 6 hours (instead of 30, 54 etc...). Are there dates somewhere? If yes, then `SUMIFS` should do the job easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this formula can help you:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$5>=0)*(--($A$2:$A$5<(1/24)+($A$2:$A$5>$B$2:$B$5))>0)*(--(($B$2:$B$5>=1/24)+($A$2:$A$5<1/24))>0))*$C$2:$C$5)
```

[image]